# Pages and Style Library libraries did not Migrate from SharePoint On-premise 2010 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2010, office365, sharepoint-online

I have migrated SharePoint On-premise 2010 content to SharePoint Online using SharePoint Migration Tools(SPMT).

When I migrate the content some of the documents libraries and lists (i.e. Pages and Style Library) content do not migrate correctly.

I have checked out the solution online. I have found the below link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/434935/sharepoint-migration-tool-not-migrationg-pages-lib.html

I have created Pages and Style Library in SharePoint online (Destination Environment). But when I try to select Pages and Style Library from SharePoint On-premise 2010 (Source Environment). It does not appear in the lists and libraries dropdown list. [Click here to view the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8s3.png)

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you get any solution for this?